# Calculate the maximum and minimum number of on and/or off days in a cycle in a period by using a formula

Tags: c#, sql-server, math

I have the problem of producing a formula for the scenario stated above. Here are the details:

The parameters:

- Period: 30 days
- On Days (in cycle): 4
- Off Days (in cycle): 4
- Cycle: 8

I want to determine the maximum and minimum amount of "on days" in a period with the cycles mentioned above with a formula. The number of on days is immediately followed by the off days. (e.g. 4 days on, 4 days off).

What I have tried is the following:

Firstly, I draw a simple schematic of the problem: The 1's is on days and 0's is off days. Each column represents one cycle. This represents the maximum number of "on days":

| Cycle 1 | Cycle 2 | Cycle 3 | Cycle 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

This table represents the maximum number of on days in the period (30). So counting all the 1's, the maximum number of "on days" is 16.

Here is the minimum number of days:

| Cycle 1 | Cycle 2 | Cycle 3 | Cycle 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |

This table represents the minimum number of on days in the period (30). So counting all the 1's, the minimum number of "on days" is 14.

Here is another example with a period of 31 days, and 6 days on and 3 days off:

| Cycle 1 | Cycle 2 | Cycle 3 | Cycle 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |  |

This table represents the maximum number of on days in the period (31). So counting all the 1's, the maximum number of "on days" is 22.

And the minimum number of "on days":

| Cycle 1 | Cycle 2 | Cycle 3 | Cycle 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |

This table represents the minimum number of "on days" in the period (31). So counting all the 1's, the minimum number of "on days" is 19.

What I have done in terms of a formula is to caluclate the number of whole cycles:

E.g. in the first example:

Number of "on days" = 30 / 8 = 3.75.

Then I took the 3 of 3.75 and multiplied it by 4 to get 12 days.
Next, I took 30 MOD 8 to get the remainder of 6 days (cycle 4).

Then I divided 6 by the number of "on days" in the cycle (4) to get 1.5.
Then I took the 1 from 1.5 and multiplied it by the number of "on days" in the cycle which gives me 4 and added that to the whole "on day" cycles (12) to get 16.

But it doesn't seem to work on the second example.

Please assist in helping with a formula or alternative approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is sql- server related to that? And honestly: I am having trouble to see what exactly you calculate and why. What is "a cycle", exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the number of days in the period by the total number of days in each cycle and round it down (e.g. 31/9 would be 3 as 9*3=27).

Multiply this number by the number of 'on' days in each cycle to get the number of 'on' days which are within a full cycle (e.g. if there were 6 'on' days per cycle you would get 18 as 3*6=18).

Now, find the remainder of the original division (with 31/9 this would be 4 as 31-27 is 4). This is how many total days are outside of full cycles.

To get the maximum number of 'on' days, if the remainder is greater than the number of 'on' days per cycle, add the number of 'on' days per cycle to the total 'on' days (currently 18 in my example). If the remainder is less, add the remainder (this is the case in my example, so you'd do 18+4=22).

To get the minimum number of 'on' days, do the remainder subtract the number of 'off' days per cycle. If this is below zero, ignore it but if it is above zero add it to the total number of 'on' days (so in my example the remainder (4) subtract the number of 'off' days per cycle (3) is 1 so the minimum number of 'on' days is 18+1=19.

Hope this helps!

P.S. If you want this as an algorithm in C# just reply and ask and I'll code it for you.